# add hash to collection of hrefs in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript, and have a case, where I need to get collection of links, get their href value and add specified hash(which I got from the window.location) to each of those href value. But I am not sure how to do it? Seems like I need to use forEach, but it does not work.
Here is the example of the code, where I got stuck.

```js
let pricesLinkHash = location.hash.substring(1);
let localeChoice = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item-hover').href;
localChoice.forEach((element) => {
  element.href += element.href + 'pricesLinkHash';
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: A hash usually means actually having a "hash" (`#`) in the URL.

Comment: `"localChoice" != "localeChoice"`

Comment: Also `document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item-hover').href` is nonsense, you can't get a list of hrefs like that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, I do have one, but I could not generate it in code snippet. I am wondering only about the logics of adding it to collection of href I have.

Comment: Also, the anchor elements do not surround the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `localeChoice` but you write `localChoice` and you need to select just `document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item-hover')` like:

```js
let pricesLinkHash = location.hash.substring(1);
let localeChoice = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item-hover');
localeChoice.forEach((element) => {
  element.href = element.href + pricesLinkHash;
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
    <li><a href="somelink" class="nav-item-hover"></a>somelink</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```